# DateDiff function in MYSQL 5.1. Need Hours+Mins

Tags: mysql, sql, select, datediff

MYSQL 5.1

I need to create a query that gives my result table three columns, match_date, match_start and match_duration

I need the match_duration column which takes match_start and match_end and displays how long each game has been on for in 00:00 hours format. So for example if it were 5hrs:30 mins it would be displayed 5:30 hours.

This is what I have so far and not sure where I'm going wrong:

```
SELECT match_date, match_start, DateDiff(hhmm, match_start, match_end) AS Duration
FROM MatchInfo;
```

Thanks

Comment: Which database system do you use? Mysql, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres?

Comment: sorry forgot to add this, I use MYSQL 5.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below:

```
  TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(match_end, match_start), '%H:%i')
```

i.e.

```
   SELECT match_date, match_start, 
          TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(match_end, match_start), '%H:%i') AS DURATION
   FROM MatchInfo;
```